# Using variable for property name in Google Earth Engine ee.Feature

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, syntaxerror

I would like to know if it is possible to set a property name using a computed variable in GEE.

For example, I create the following feature:

```
var feature = ee.Feature(null,{propertyName: 0.85});
```

and would like to be able to use a property name which was previously defined, so instead of using "propertyName" I would use `var propertyName = 'propertyValue'` .

I found [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153969/create-object-using-variables-for-property-name) relating to JavaScript in general which states that you may place the variable name in between brackets.

```
var foo = "bar";
var ob  = { [foo]: "something" }; // ob.bar === "something"
```

However trying the same notation in GEE only produced an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var feature = ee.Feature(null).set(propertyName, 0.85);
```

This will also work if `propertyName` Earth Engine computed/server-side string values, not just JavaScript strings.